# Is there something wrong w/ this code?

Tags: wp-query

```
<?php
    $rp = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post','videos','projects' ),
    'orderby' => 'date&order=DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
    ));

    while ($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();
?>
```

I noticed that if I change `date&order=DESC` to `rand`, it makes no difference, meaning the posts don't show up in random order even after multiple refreshes. Is there something wrong w/ this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be this:
[WP_Query Order By Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

```
<?php
    $rp = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post','videos','projects' ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
    ));

    while ($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why inserting `rand` into `orderby` wouldn't work?

Comment: @jwp - The `orderby` parameter specifies which column's values you want to order. The `order` parameter specifies how those values should be ordered. (ASC, DESC, rand, ...)

Comment: I did try entering the `rand` value into the `order` parameter and unfortunately it still didn't work. Also, the link in your post states that `rand` should go under the `orderby` parameter. I'm confused because neither work.

Comment: Add `surpress_filters` to the query, there's no reason it shouldn't work with `rand` other than when some function is hooked on and changing query parameters(surpress_filters will fix that for you though).